# How to move files in source path to destination path via python?

Tags: python

I have information data from Excel file.I need to move all files in Source Path(Columns A) to Backup Path (Column F). Like this :

[image]

This's my code:

```
import os
import shutil
ie = ["G:/01-FIN & ACC/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/02-BDSM (ห้ามย้ายเด็ดขาด)-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/03-BSC/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/04-CLD-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/05-COMPLIANCE-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/06-CRD-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/07-HR-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/08-IT-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/09-MGT-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/10-MKT-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/"]
#Backup Path
backup_ie = ["G:/01-FIN & ACC-Confidential/Backup/IE/",
"G:/02-BDSM-Confidential/Backup/IE/",
"G:/03-BSC-Confidential/Backup/IE/",
"G:/04-CLD-Confidential/Backup/IE/",
"G:/05-COMPLIANCE-Confidential/Backup/IE/",
"G:/06-CRD-Confidential/Backup/IE/",
"G:/07-HR-Confidential/Backup/IE/",
"G:/08-IT-Confidential/Backup/IE/",
"G:/09-MGT-Confidential/Backup/IE/",
"G:/10-MKT-Confidential/Backup/IE/"]

for x in backup_ie: #Copy to backup
    shutil.copyfile(ie, x) #Copy to backup
```

Please tell me hpw to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi veerachai,

Your description and your code do not tell the same story. Do you want to move the files (like you said in your title) so that in the end there will be only files only in the destination or do you want to copy (or backup like you have mentioned in the comments of you code) so that in the end you have two copies of the files, one that wasn't touched in the source and one at the destination?

Answer (score 0):

`shutil.copyfile(src, dest)` copies file content from **source** to **destination**.
Use `shutil.move(src, dest)` to move file to **destination folder**

> You haven't provided the file-name in either the source and the destination in above code.